# cuppa-ng2-slidemenu - Changing margin-top and re-sizing icons

Tags: css, angularjs, overriding

Demo of slide menu in the top left of the page:
https://cuppalabs.github.io/cuppa-ng2-slidemenu/

Using the Google Tools I have been able to change the margin-top of the menu, but I've had no luck doing the same with my own copy.

**My best attempt:**

```
cuppa-slide-menu span div .menu-container .cuppa-menu .show-menu, 
cuppa-slide-menu span div .menu-container .cuppa-menu .hide-menu {
    margin-top: 134px !important;
}
```

I have also been unable to locate the css file located at `src="/path/to/angularjs/angular.min.js"`

Regarding the icon sizes, I was unable to do it even on Google Chrome.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a css file as such, the styles are included in the js files, I have been able to change the margin of the menu by writing the following in my stylesheet:

```
.cuppa-menu-overlay, .menu-container[_ngcontent-c3]{
  margin-top: 150px !important;
}
```

[And the result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tphu0.png)

I hope I have helped, greetings